# How to measure table saw torque and horsepower?

Tags: induction-motor

I have a table saw that has the following rating:

```
120V at 60Hz
standard 5/8" arbor
```

I took the following measurements to see how they compared with the advertised specs. The below are the actual numbers measured.

```
RPM: 4,850.4
No load amp draw: 8.7A
No load voltage (taken at same time as amp draw): 114.0
```

This is a direct drive induction motor, so I'm assuming the efficiency is somewhere in the 95%+ range.

I can't seem to get a straight answer on other websites. Is there more information needed or can I get within a tenth or two of the actual horsepower rating with these numbers?

Comment: It's all curves. Not single values. It's common to use a dynamometer along with a process for using it that in the end graphs torque, speed, and power over a range. Also, measuring current separately from voltage doesn't tell you much, as they are taken independently and can't be directly combined.

Comment: With no load I would say the efficiency is much closer to zero.

Comment: No load numbers tell you nothing. The RPM will vary with the torque and the torque will vary with the material you are cutting. Neither torque nor RPM are constant. Even with loaded numbers you can't tell with with no efficiency curves. And 95% seems really optimistic. 1/10HP? You'd be lucky to get within 10%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is there more information needed or can I get within a tenth or two of
> the actual horsepower rating with these numbers?*

You need to measure the supply voltage and current when the motor is on full-load and, you need to account for the power factor of the device. So, in a nutshell, you use a wattmeter and let it tell you the power input. Because you know the power output, you can calculate the efficiency but, it's likely to be significantly less than 95%.

No load figures of voltage and current tell you virtually nothing about full-load power or efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds a lot like my inexpensive BT-3100 table saw, which has a noisy smallish brushed 4800 RPM universal motor. And is a bit underpowered.

Theoretical sustained maximum for a 15A 120VAC outlet is a bit less than 2.5HP with 100% efficiency, though you can find claims of 4, 5, 6 or more HP (aka "Sears HP"). Not wanting to get sued for their claims, the actual HP is often omitted from official manuals and documents. A bit like "peak music power" claims that sometimes overstated audio amplifier output power capability by an order of magnitude*. I would guess it's closer to 1HP maximum output power under typical cutting conditions, and efficiency is probably 50 or 60% tops. Yours may be similar.

It's easy enough to measure true input power with an inexpensive power meter, divide by 745 for *input* HP, however that does not tell you the power that is coming out of the shaft. Measurements of current and voltage don't tell the whole picture because the power factor will not be 1, so a power meter is required.

With no load, there is no useful output power, but input power is substantial (efficiency is 0). If the motor is stalled, again input power is even more substantial but no output power is produced (efficiency is 0). Somewhere in the middle there will be a maxima for efficiency and another maxima for output power.

As others have said, there will be a peak at some combination of RPM and torque and lower output horsepower on either side of that. The motor manufacturer will have supplied such curves to the saw OEM.

* My favorite was the "30W" computer speakers that operated from a 9V 200mA wall wart.

Answer (score 1):

> 120V at 60Hz

All that tells you is that it is designed for ordinary US/Canada consumer usage.

> standard 5/8" arbor

And all that tells you is what size blades it uses.

None of that tells you anything about how powerful or efficient it is.

Somewhere on the nameplate should be additional information. Most likely, it is designed for a 15A circuit, so that puts an upper limit on the input power, though it can safely exceed the circuit breaker rating for a short period of time.

> RPM: 4,850.4

That tells you how fast it can spin *with no load*, which doesn't say much. It may indicate the *type* of motor (thank you Harper) but it doesn't say anything about how powerful it is.

> No load amp draw: 8.7A

That is a somewhat useful number, but *no load* and *load* are two very different situations. With a real load (cutting into stuff), the RPM will go down, the Amp draw will go up and you will, potentially, get some useful information.

> No load voltage (taken at same time as amp draw): 114.0

Doesn't mean much. Your starting voltage could be anywhere from 114 to 125 (though most places in the US, most of the time, will be very close to 120). Again, what happens under load is what matters.

Comment: 4850 RPM tells you a great deal, it says it's not a common induction motor, which would be spinning at nameplate 1725 or 3450 RPM *because 60Hz*.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't "re-invent the wheel".  Stand on the shoulders of giants.

For things which are not reciprocating piston fuel engines, horsepower is complicated. (quick, what's the horsepower of the CFM56 jet engine found on the 737-800?)

With an induction motor, you have a complicated and weird torque/RPM curve that resists somewhat establishing a single max horsepower number.  So you find yourself trying to nail Jell-o to a wall.

[image: Graph of current / torque vs. speed for induction motor]

Image source: [The Engineering Toolbox - Electrical Induction Motors - Slip](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/electrical-motor-slip-d_652.html)

However, the electrical industry already decided how to settle this question.  You are better off relying on this standard.   The nameplate data on the motor will state this figure.

Comment: CFM-56 delivers zero power just before take-off roll :-)

Answer (score 1):

Horsepower and torque of a motor are not certain fixed numbers, they depend on the exact applied voltage (it drops due the resistance of the wires when the load increases) and how much the motor is mechanically loaded (reduces the r.p.m) A part of the in-motor generated torque and mechanical power is lost to friction before it makes anything useful to your wooden workpiece.

If you are incredibly lucky you can find the exact type of the used motor and see in motor manufacturer's data the torque as a function of the revolution speed with different operating voltages. Then you can estimate the motor output power by multiplying the r.p.m as radians per second by the torque as newtonmeters. The resulted power is in watts. But you must know which r.p.m is the interesting one and the result does not take into the account mechanical losses.

I'm afraid no motor specs can be found because tool manufacturers can order custom types. No pure electrical measurements reveal mechanical quantities, so the remaining possibility is to make mechanical measurements. Constructing a known mechanical load - for ex. one which lifts some easily adjustable mass - is easy to think and say but making it in practice is far from easy. Proper construction needs skills which are beyond what's needed in tinkering with circuits and electric measurements. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The power output of your motor is not a fixed number, it depends on the load that is presented.  At no load, power output is what is required to match friction, windage, magnetic and electrical losses.   When you feed a board into the blade, power output increases to meet the additional load.

Nameplate ratings specify only one operating point: rated load.  Basically, this is the full continuous load the the motor is designed for.  You can operate at rated load; you can exceed rated load, at least briefly. Exceeding rated load can result in overheating or tripping of protection devices, but the motor is capable. Efficiency very much depends on the operation point.

No load current measurements don't tell you much.  An unloaded induction motor electrically looks pretty much like an inductor, so its power factor is low. Also, its speed should be close to synchronous speed.  Which brings up a question: How are you measuring speed?  Synchronous speed for a 60Hz line-powered 2-pole induction motor is 3600 rpm